# Strings are not written to a new line

Tags: java, file-io, newline

Following snippet attempts to write the name of directories and files present in some directory to a text file.Each name should be written to a separate line.Instead it prints each name on the same line. Why is it so ?

```
        try {
        File listFile = new File("E:" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Shiv Kumar Sharma Torrent"+ System.getProperty("file.separator") +"list.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(listFile,true);
        Iterator iterator = directoryList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            writer.write((String)iterator.next());
            writer.write("\n"); // Did this so each name is on a new line
        }
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*output:*

[image]

Where am i making a mistake ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenver you need textual formatting always use [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).
The right way of doing is to wrap the writer inside a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and use println() method, like:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
printWriter.println();
```

Comment: Actually, `newLine()` is a method of `BufferedWriter` class.

Comment: +1 for advising of using `PrintWriter` rather than `FileWriter`:)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows, use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

or for OS-independent, use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write your next line as "\r\n" if you are on a Windows platform.

The next line for Windows is "\r\n"

The next line for Mac is "\n"

Alternatively, use System.getProperty("line.separator") for your line break. It automatically determines the right line break for the system it is running on. This should be the best practice since Java is expected to perform the same on different OS-es.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use BufferedWriter :

```
 File f = new File("C:/file.txt");
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
 bw.write("Hello");
 bw.newLine();   // new line
 bw.write("How are you?");
 bw.close();
```